# push() function is not adding to the end of array, is instead replacing index 0 with pushed object

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I have a prompt asking a user for a number(guess), until they guess a randomly selected number(num). I'm trying to keep track of these guesses by putting them in an array.

```
 let guessesArray = [];

if (guess == num && guess != NaN) {
    guessesArray.push(guess);
    message.innerHTML = "You got it! It took you " + guessesArray.length +
        " tries and your guesses were " + guessesArray + ".";

}
else if (guess > num && guess != NaN) {
    if (guess <= max) {
        guessesArray.push(guess);
        message.innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";

    } etc...
```

as i watch the console while guessing numbers, every time the push function is used, it just replaces the value at index 0. so when the user finds the correct answer, the message they receive is always that they got the answer in 1 guess and what should be a list of numbers that they guessed, is instead just the last number they guessed. How can I properly append to an array in JS?

```
function do_guess() {
    let guess = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);
    let guessesArray = [];

    if (guess == num && guess != NaN) {
        guessesArray.push(guess);
        message.innerHTML = "You got it! It took you " + guessesArray.length +
            " tries and your guesses were " + guessesArray + ".";

    }
    else if (guess > num && guess != NaN) {
        if (guess <= max) {
            guessesArray.push(guess);
            message.innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";

        }
        else {
            message.innerHTML = "That number is not in range, try again.";
        }
    }
    else if (guess < num && guess != NaN) {
        if (0 < guess) {
            guessesArray.push(guess);
            message.innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
        }
        else {
            message.innerHTML = "That number is not in range, try again.";
        }

    }
    else {
        message.innerHTML = "That is not a number!";
    }
    console.log(guessesArray);
}
```

Comment: Please post a full piece of code where the issue is reproducible. Please avoid usage of etc.

Comment: `guess != NaN` doesn't work like you think it does. To make sure `guess` isn't `NaN` you need to use the `isNaN` method like `!isNaN(guess)`.

Comment: I'm going for a Hail Mary here but aren't you resetting the array to empty every single iteration with let guessesArray = [];

Comment: I second @JorgeGuerreiro. Please move the `let guessesArray = [];` declaration to the outer scope of function: `do_guess`

Comment: @Thijs i actually am able to get reproducibly correct results with guess!=NaN format i think? i haven't had any issues with that part

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro you're right, dumb mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call the `do_guess` method you're resetting `guessesArray` to an empty array (line 3). You need to define `guessesArray` outside of your method if you want it to retain the values you've pushed into it.

Comment: this was the issue, thanks!